# Separate arrays from main script file

Tags: javascript, arrays, readability

I'm working on a Javascript code that generates random text from smaller sets of strings. The problem is that to make the code easy to read and to expand, I definitely have to use one line for each string variables.

Something like this, very broadly.

```
var array = [
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text",
...
]

var array_b = [
//(the same again)
]

var result = array[math.floor(math.random())] + " " + array_b[math.floor(math.random())]
```

Needless to say, it's quite uncomfortable. Not impossible to get used to, obviously; but if it's possible, I'd get rid of those long arrays.

Is there a way for it? Putting them into a different file, calling them from another script of another page maybe? Or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the array into a JSON(JavaScript Object Notation) file, then use an ajax request to load them

**data.json**

```
["text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text",...]
```

**main.js**

```
//if using jQuery
jQuery.ajax({
  url:"data.json",
  dataType:"json"
}).then(function(data){
   //'data' will be your array use it
});

//if not using jQuery
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //parse the JSON text
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //call a function passing it the array
        response(data);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.json");
xmlhttp.send();

function response(data){
   //data will be your array use it
}
```

You can also just add them to a separate js file and add a second `<script>` element

**data.js**

```
var data =["text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text",...]
```

**main.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add them in another file as long as you make sure to load them both and make sure they are on the global window object. This means that instead of using

`var array_a = []`

you use:

`window.array_a = []`

and in the current file (where you do all the work) you reference them as `window.array_a` instead of just `array_a`.

Additionally, depending on the editor you're using, it will most likely allow you to collapse any such arrays or function declarations for the reasons you're describing, which would also fix the problem. An example would be Sublime Text.

Comment: You are perfectly right about the collapse thing; sadly though, I'm working with the given editor of Tumblr, so that's not going to work. Uploading a JS script is also tricky apparently (at least I have no idea, how does it work on Tumblr), but I'll surely find a way for it - or change to Wordpress in worst case. Thank you very much!